# search master data service member by builtin attribute code

Tags: c#, sql-server, master-data-services

I can search member by `EntityMembersGetCriteria` where `SearchTerm` containing expressions for custom attributes for exampel `SAP Code = 'abc'`.

```
var criteria = new EntityMembersGetCriteria
        {
            ModelId = new Identifier { Name = Model },
            EntityId = new Identifier { Name = Entity },
            VersionId = new Identifier { Name = Version },
            SearchTerm = searchTerm,
            MemberType = MemberType.Leaf,
            MemberReturnOption = MemberReturnOption.DataAndCounts
        };
```

However it does work with `Code='xyz'`.

Any idea pls?

Comment: Is the issue that it is not recognizing 'SAP Code' but is recognizing 'Code';or it is not finding 'abc' and is finding 'xyz'?

Comment: Name and Code are builtin attributes in MDS. I can not search with this 2 attributes but can do with others.

Answer (score 0):

SearchTerm sets WHERE clause search criteria to filter records. That means it is needed to put **exactly the same names as it is stored in the MDS DB**.

The point is that the **user defined attributes (UDA) have special names in MDS DB**.

Every UDA attributes is stored in the following format:
`uda_{Entity.InternalId}_{Attribute.InternalId}`, for example uda_2012_45231. In case of **Entity.InternalId** = 2021 and **Attribute.InternalId** = 45231.

So you have write into SearchTerm:

```
"uda_2012_45231 = 'abc'"
```

P.S.: You can find the values of the Entity and Attribute InternalIds within [MetadataGet method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.masterdataservices.metadatagetrequest?view=sqlserver-2016).

**UPDATE**: It seems that UDA attributes do not work within SearchTerm at all. "Name", "Code", "EnterDTM" (*CreatedDateTime*) and "LastChgDTM" (*UpdatedDateTime*) are working, but the UDA are not.